# C++ - Add map to map with lambda

Tags: c++, lambda, std

I just wonder if there is any *sexy* way in C++ (using standard library functions) to do something like that:

I've got two maps (std::map), both same type. I'd like to add both maps together, but also decide which elements add and which not with some lambda predicate.

Any solution? Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to create a third map or mutate one of the two input maps?

Comment: Random thoughts: `std::merge`, `std::set_union`, `std::multimap`, and also consider whether `a.key_comp() == b.key_comp()` (comparators may be stateful!).

Comment: I don't want to use 3rd map, because all elements inside of first map stays, predicate would only determine addition of 2nd map's elements.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `std::copy_if` in combination with `std::inserter`. This example only adds elements from `b` into `a` if the value is even:

```
std::copy_if(b.begin(), b.end(), std::inserter(a, a.end()),
             [](auto&& e){return e.second%2 == 0;});
```

You could factor this out into a helper function if you find yourself needing this a few times:

```
template <typename T, typename F>
void merge_maps (T& a, const T& b, const F& filter) { 
    std::copy_if(b.begin(), b.end(), std::inserter(a, a.end()), filter);
}

merge_maps(a, b, [](auto&& e){return e.second%2 == 0;});
```